# visual studio empty web application image fadeOut on PageLoad

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Im trying to fadeOut image on page load. Im new in Jquery but i need some help because i didnt find working answers in google , what am i missing

WebForm1.aspx

```
@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Zzz.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <script type="text/javascript" id="fadeout">
         $(body).ready(function () {
             $('#Image1').fadeOut(3000);
         });

     </script>

</head>
<body onload="fadeout">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Style =" position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px;left:10px;top:10px; " ImageUrl="~/Photos/facebook.jpg"  />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Zzz
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You aren't referencing the jquery library.
2. Use `$(document).ready(function() {...})` or `$(function() {...})`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>    
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#Image1').fadeOut(3000);
     });
</script>
```

To execute from your .cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Zzz
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "$('#Image1').fadeOut(3000);", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: btw what about if i want to execute this function from aspx.cs

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery library, in the head or your page, put this (I use a CDN, but you can get it locally):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And you need to use the correct statement for page loaded, and, most important, **the correct statement for identify the element (ASP.NET adds text to ASP elements ID, so you need get that id form the framework):**

```
$(function () {
    $('#<%=Image1.ClientID%>').fadeOut(3000);
});
```

Finally, an advice, if you can, start your projects using ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Only if you use MasterPages, which the poster is not